# Get links via ImportXML from Google Search Results

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am trying to get links via a google sheet from the Google Search Results:

I am using the following formula:

```
=ImportXML(CONCATENATE("http://www.google.de/search?q={site:www.amazon.de ",B3,"}&num=",D3), "//h3[@class='r']/a/@href")
```

Below you can find the spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S0GI0d_J_8GxUp24631NDhzA_G__ihRRGeOJ5Re7N54/edit?usp=sharing

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: You should include all the important details on the question itself. Don't force people to open the demo spreadsheet to see if there is an error message or a wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

Two things - one is you can eliminate the concatenate function and use `&` instead - its simpler and has the exact same effect  - 2 you can use regex replace in the format of an arrayformula to transform the resulting strings into real URLs:

```
`=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(IMPORTXML("https://www.google.de/search?q={site:www.amazon.de "&B1&"}&num="&C1"//h3/a/@href"),"(^.*q=)(.*)(&sa.*)","$2"))`
```

For the URL using the &, it looks like this:

`https://www.google.de/search?q={site:www.amazon.de "&B1&"}&num="&C1`

And the xpath I simplified to `//h3/a/@href` this isnt necessary but a bit simpler..

And the REGEXREPLACE Function, I created 3 capture groups, represented by surrounding parentheses:

`(^.*q=)` `(.*)` `(&sa.*)`

followed by the `"$2"` as the third parameter to direct it to pull out the `SECOND` capture group which is the actual website URL your trying to get.

By using Arrayformula around all of it - it will apply it to all the rows, and not just the first one

[image]